# Isabelle termination of function on datatypes containing maps to themselves

Tags: isabelle

Is it possible in Isabelle to define a terminating recursive function `f` where

- `f` has a single parameter of type `t` such that values of type `t` may contain maps to values of type `t`, and
- `f` performs its recursive calls on all elements in the range of such a map?

For example consider the datatype `trie` defined in theory [Trie_Fun](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL-Data_Structures/Trie_Fun.html):

```
datatype 'a trie = Nd bool "'a ⇒ 'a trie option"
```

and my attempt at a simple function `height` intended to compute the height of tries (with finitely many outgoing edges):

```
theory Scratch
  imports "HOL-Data_Structures.Trie_Fun"
begin

function height :: "'a trie ⇒ nat" where
  "height (Nd _ edges) = (if dom edges = Set.empty ∨ ¬ finite (dom edges)
    then 0
    else 1 + Max (height ` ran edges))"
  by pat_completeness auto
termination (* ??? *)

end
```

Here `lexicographic_order` does not suffice to prove the function to be terminating, but so far I have also not been able to formulate any measure on `trie` (for termination) that does not itself require a similar recursion.
I must admit here that I am not sure whether I have understood datatypes in Isabelle/HOL correctly (i.e., whether a `trie` of the above definition is actually always of finite height).

Is it possible to show that `height` terminates?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `function (domintros)` option to the declaration and then using induction for the terminating proof?

Comment: Thank you very much, this was indeed sufficient to prove termination. Would you like to submit your comment as an answer or may I answer the question myself based on your comment?

Comment: Would be nice if you could add the answer yourself, including the working termination proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based to the comment by Peter Zeller, I was able to prove termination of `height` by adding `(domintros)` to the definition and then performing induction on the `trie`, using the fact `height.domintros`, resulting in the following termination proof:

```
function (domintros) height :: "'a trie ⇒ nat" where
  "height (Nd _ edges) = (if dom edges = Set.empty ∨ ¬ finite (dom edges)
    then 0
    else 1 + Max (height ` ran edges))"
  by pat_completeness auto
termination apply auto
proof -
  fix x :: "'a trie"
  show "height_dom x"
  proof (induction)
    case (Nd b edges)

    have "(⋀x. x ∈ ran edges ⟹ height_dom x)"
    proof -
      fix x assume "x ∈ ran edges" 
      then have "∃a. edges a = Some x"
        unfolding ran_def by blast
      then have "∃a. Some x = edges a"
        by (metis (no_types))
      then have "Some x ∈ range edges"
        by blast
      then show "height_dom x"
        using Nd by auto
    qed
    then show ?case
      using height.domintros by blast
  qed
qed
```